# Appending rows to CSV in Python with column-specific duplicate filter

Tags: python, list, csv, append

So I want Python, using the csv reader/writer, to take all of the CSVs in a directory and combine them, while filtering out any rows that contain a duplicate of any other row's value in the second column.

Here's my unworking script:

```
import csv
import glob

with open('merged.csv','a') as out:
    seen = set()
    output = []
    out_writer = csv.writer(out)
    csv_files = [f for f in glob.glob('*.csv') if 'merged' not in f]
#csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv') 
     # I'd like to use all files including the output so that I don't
     # have to rename it when reusing the script - it should dupe-filter itself!
for filename in csv_files:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as ifile:
        read = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=',')
        for row in read:
            if row[1] not in seen:
                seen.add(row[1])
                if row: #was getting extra rows
                    output.append(row)
out_writer.writerows(output)
```

I feel like I must be missing something simple.  My files are around 100MB in size each, and I eventually want to automate this so that different computers can share a merged file for dupe-checking.

For extra credit, how would I change this to check for rows that have both `row[1]` and `row[2]` in common?  (Once the dupe-filter and self-inclusion are working, of course...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more than the small number of lines that pandas might require, since it's stock Python, but on the other hand it's relatively straight-forward, will filter on multiple column values, and handles re-reading previous results. It use the`fileinput`module to allow it to treat its multiple input files as a single continuous stream of rows of data.

```
import csv
import fileinput
import glob
import os

merged_csv = 'merged.csv'
columns = (1, 2)  # columns used for filtering
pathname = '*.csv'
tmpext = os.extsep + "tmp"
csv_files = glob.glob(pathname)

if merged_csv not in csv_files:
    prev_merged = None
else:
    prev_merged = merged_csv + tmpext
    os.rename(merged_csv, prev_merged)
    csv_files[csv_files.index(merged_csv)] = prev_merged

with open(merged_csv, 'wb') as ofile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    written = set()  # unique combinations of column values written
    csv_stream = fileinput.input(csv_files, mode='rb')
    for row in csv.reader(csv_stream, delimiter=','):
        combination = tuple(row[col] for col in columns)
        if combination not in written:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
            written.add(combination)

if prev_merged:
    os.unlink(prev_merged)  # clean up

print '{!r} file {}written'.format(merged_csv, 're' if prev_merged else '')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using pandas rather than csv writer.  I would rewrite your code to something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file) for
                  file in glob.glob("*.csv")]).drop_duplicates(cols=COLNAME_LIST)
data.to_csv('merged.csv')
```

In full disclosure I haven't tested this code as I don't have a ton of csv files lying around, but I've written similar things before with success

Comment: Heck, if you're feeling all sorts of Halloween crazy, you could even make it a one-liner `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file) for file in glob.glob("*.csv")]).drop_duplicates(cols=COLNAME_LIST).to_csv('merged.csv')`

Comment: Awesome - I've been thinking of working with pandas, because I actually have a lot of this kind of stuff to work with.  It makes more sense to get in now than to wait till it's necessary and have to translate everything.  Will this only check for duplicates as per column 2, or will it drop anything that dupes on any column entry?  I really need to look up the basics on pandas.

Comment: You can pass it a list of columns that you want to check for duplicates in (see COLNAME_LIST) above.  It helps to have labels on your columns (Can be done just by having the first line in your file be the header names), but if you don't, they'll just have numeric headers.  Another thing you should watch out for is indices, as they are automatically created as the first value in each line.  I'm not sure how your csv files are structured, but hopefully that's not an issue for you.  Not a big deal either way

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'concat'`

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I'm on 0.12

Comment: 0.12 for Windows, 32-bit, Python 2.7 -- EDIT: I'm a windows noob and didn't properly install all dependencies.  Don't know why a lack of the dateutil threw this error, but things are working fine now.

Comment: If I use `drop_duplicates(cols=col1name,col2name)`, does that drop duplicates that contain the same values in col1name AND col2name (what I want), or col1name OR col2name (way too severe).

Comment: I'm going to do you a favor here and let you try that one out for yourself.  Build a dataframe with both cases, run `drop_duplicates` on it and check the result.  This is in part me being lazy, but it'll take 3 minutes and lead to more exploration / understanding of pandas